# How do you deploy a custom web service within a WSP file?

Tags: 2007, web-services, solution-package

I can deploy my assembly in a wsp to our MOSS 2007 server but I can't seem to find any information about how to automatically deploy my .asmx, disco.aspx and wdsl.aspx files at the same time.

Is this always a manual process of the files into the ISAPI folder in the 12s or can it be automated in the WSP some how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the manifest file yourself but more popular and easier way in MOSS 2007 was by using [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/).

You create the same folder structure in your project starting from 12 folder to ISAPI folder. Put your files there, right click the project -> WSPBuilder -> Build WSP. 
You can then install that WSP.

If you are curious and want to see how the tool has done it you can extract the generated WSP and check the manifest file.

Comment: I used WSPBuilder as a guide, although I continued to use my own way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

In your project, add the mapped Layout folder to your solution and within it create a subfolder in which you add your webservice (`.asmx`) file.

You can then call your custom webservice by url like so:

```
/_layouts/MagicalWebservices/MagicalWebservice.asmx
```

Build/package your solution and you're good to go.

Comment: Does this work for MOSS 2007?

Comment: @Naim as far as I know, yes.

Comment: Thanks. AFAIK the procedure you described is possible only with SharePoint Solution template in Visual Studio for SP 2010 and up. That’s why we use WSPBuilder for MOSS 2007.... last time I checked:).